# cordova FileChooser plugin getting real path of selected file

Tags: java, android

I add this plugin to my cordova project that is make me able to chose file, then it return the path of this file. My problem is the returned path is not real path, it is `content://media/external/images/media/2144`. I want to convert this URI to real path such as `storage/sdcard0/DCIM/camera/321321321.jpg`
this is plugin code in java, what should I modify?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.CordovaArgs;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class FileChooser extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String TAG = "FileChooser";
    private static final String ACTION_OPEN = "open";
    private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
    CallbackContext callback;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, CordovaArgs args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals(ACTION_OPEN)) {
            chooseFile(callbackContext);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void chooseFile(CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        // type and title should be configurable

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);

        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File");
        cordova.startActivityForResult(this, chooser, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);

        PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
        callback = callbackContext;
        callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST && callback != null) {

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                if (uri != null) {

                    Log.w(TAG, uri.toString());
                    callback.success(uri.toString());

                } else {

                    callback.error("File uri was null");

                }

            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // TODO NO_RESULT or error callback?
                PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
                callback.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

            } else {

                callback.error(resultCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```